# Get HiveContext using Spark/Java Maven project

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use HiveContext for getting the value from the table using Spark SQL.

But i am not sure how to configure hive metastore details and make it working.

DO we need to set somethikng on `SparkContext`()?

Regards,
Shankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables):

```
HiveContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc.sc);
```

> Configuration of Hive is done by placing your hive-site.xml file in conf/.

And example [hive-site.xml](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/test/resources/data/conf/hive-site.xml).

Comment: If i want to work in Eclipse / STS tool where should i place the hive-site.xml file. Do i need to place it under resources folder? please help me on this.

Comment: See [this](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/How-is-hive-site-xml-loaded-td11554.html). Moreover `HiveContext` has `setConf` method so you should be able to use this to override some specific values.